# JasperReport: Printwhen expression on Export-type

Tags: jasper-reports

is it possible to make an printWhen expression for a exported type?

for example, I will print a label only when the report is exported to pdf, in the html version I don't will print the label.

regards

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JasperReports: hide textfield when not HTML view](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8044930/jasperreports-hide-textfield-when-not-html-view)

Answer (score 0):

Yes. But normally it's done for a full band. See [How can I suppress page headers and footers when exporting to XLS?](http://jasperforge.org/website/jasperreportswebsite/trunk/faq.html?group_id=252#FAQ28) in the [JasperReports FAQ](http://jasperforge.org/website/jasperreportswebsite/trunk/faq.html). It uses XLS as the example, but you can do the same for HTML.

Answer (score 0):

I think this might work:

```
net.sf.jasperreports.export.{format}.exclude.key.{suffix}
```

[Additional info](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/config.reference.html#net.sf.jasperreports.export.%7Bformat%7D.exclude.key.%7Bsuffix%7D)