# Want to filter elements of last page footer according to formats in jasper report

Tags: jasper-reports, reporting, ireport

I want my report to export in HTML, EXCEL, WORD and PDF formats.

In Last page footer band I placed two fields page no. and printed date. In WORD and PDF formats, I want to print both elements but in EXCEL and HTML formats want to print only printed date.

How can I achieve this ?

Comment: You can find the answer on your question in this topic: [JasperReports: hide textfield when not HTML view](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8044930/jasperreports-hide-textfield-when-not-html-view)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look [`here`](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/config.reference.html)

Simply set jasperreport properties:

*`prop : net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.exclude.origin.band.xyz`*

*`value: LastPageFooter`*