# Export report in xls format without group Column Header in adf

Tags: jakarta-ee, jasper-reports, oracle-adf

I am generating a jasper report using an ADF Application in XLS format but there a two issues with this report:

1. Some rows and columns are merged .Due to this aggregate operations can not be performed well on the xls report.
2. Column Headers are repeated again and again.

Code:

```
else if( "xls".equalsIgnoreCase(reporttype) )
{
    response.setContentType("application/xls");
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachement; filename=\"TrialBalance_GroupWiseConsolidate.xls\"");

    exporter = new JRXlsExporter();                     
    exporter.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_DETECT_CELL_TYPE, Boolean.TRUE);
    exporter.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_WHITE_PAGE_BACKGROUND, Boolean.FALSE);
    exporter.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_REMOVE_EMPTY_SPACE_BETWEEN_ROWS, Boolean.TRUE );
    exporter.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_REMOVE_EMPTY_SPACE_BETWEEN_COLUMNS, Boolean.TRUE );
    exporter.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_COLLAPSE_ROW_SPAN, Boolean.TRUE);
    exporter.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_IGNORE_GRAPHICS, Boolean.FALSE);
    exporter.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.is, Boolean.FALSE);

    exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT, jasperPrint);
    exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.OUTPUT_STREAM, ouputStream);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**For Second point:**

add below property in xml:

`<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.exclude.origin.keep.first.band.1" value="pageHeader"/>`

You can remove other bands also, just add a property with their value as to remove footer:

`<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.exclude.origin.band.4" value="pageFooter"/>`

This will remove footer from all the pages of `xls`.

For further reference have a look at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8044930/jasperreports-hide-textfield-when-not-html-view)