# Display page number of document only when printing the document in jasper report

Tags: jasper-reports

I need to display the page number of the pdf document only when printing the document.Do not show when viewing the document.We are using jasper report to generate the report

Comment: `I need to display the page number of the pdf document only when printing the document.Do not show when viewing the document.` - Are you talking about the same *pdf* document?

Comment: You can add the condition for showing textFields depends on external parameter

Comment: If viewing the report in HTML and only using PDF for printing, AlexK has an excellent [answer on excluding fields](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8047131/5191221).

Comment: @AlexK thanks for your reply 
but my requirement is i do not want to display page number when viewing the pdf but have to display while printing the pdf.

Comment: @rajeesh Do you have a sample of such *pdf* file?

Comment: @AlexK  currently i dont have such document now,actually this is a requirement have to implement in my work.