# Detect Export Jasper Report Form

Tags: jasper-reports

I have a problem to switch print variables in jasper report based on what the report exports to. Let's say I have 2 fields in jasper report : $F{A} and $F{B}.
The jasper should print $F{A} if it exports using rtf (Rich Text Format), and print $F{B} if it exports using other than rtf.

What must I write in the jasper textField?
Is there any function as exportedAs("rtf")?
`<textFieldExpression><![CDATA[(exportedAs("rtf")? $F{A} : $F{A})]]></textFieldExpression>`

------ Add new information here ------

I have tried to use <exporter_property_prefix>.exclude.key

`<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.rtf.exclude.key.NOTRTFFIELD"/>`

And let the other print is pdf.
`<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.rtf.exclude.key.NOTPDFFIELD"/>`

I put keys in report element as well.

```
<code>
<reportElement key="NOTRTFFIELD">
<reportElement key="NOTPDFFIELD">
</code>
```

But when $F{A} and $F{B} has different number of lines, it will leave empty space for the field which has less line.

i.e.
$F{A} :

line A1

line A2

line A3
$F{B} :

line B1

Assume $F{A} is printed when report export as PDF and $F{B} is printed when report export as RTF.
If we print as PDF :

`other line...
line A1
line A2
line A3
other line...`

If we print as RTF :
`other line...
line B1
                  ---blank line---
                  ---blank line---
other line...`



I have to remove those blank lines..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JasperReports: hide textfield when not HTML view](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8044930/jasperreports-hide-textfield-when-not-html-view)

Comment: You can use: `<exporter_property_prefix>.exclude.key`

Comment: or just use a parameter, are you exporting via java or are you using jasper-server?

Comment: I export via java. I wish I could use parameter, but if I do that, I have to update the current framework. It's not allowed and it takes time if I have to do that.

Answer (score 2):

If you can use different text fields, `net.sf.jasperreports.export.{format}.exclude.key.{suffix}` properties might help.

See jasper-reports [config.reference](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/config.reference.html#net.sf.jasperreports.export.%7Bformat%7D.exclude.key.%7Bsuffix%7D)

Comment: I have tried that, but if the height of text is difference, then the less high text will leave empty space. Assume : $F{A} contains 3 lines. $F{B} contains 5 lines. Then if the text print $F{A}, the next 2 line become empty lines, because $F{B} contains 2 more lines. I need to remove this empty lines.

Comment: There are properties also for this, removeWhenBlank=true and  positionType=float

Comment: I have put isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" as reportElement attribute, but it does not remove the blank lines

Comment: @user3859858 You will need positionType="float" on the other elements, maybe the easiest way for you is to pass a parameter

Comment: I have used positionType=true but the blank lines still appear. I can't pass a parameter because I have to update the framework. It's not allowed in my company's rule.